# Does the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (2,1)} \frac{4-xy}{x^2+3y^2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that to find the limit for the above function, we can just simply substitute in $x=2$ and $y=1$ into the function since the function is continuous at $x=2$ and $y=1$.

The problem that I have over here is that when I restrict the function to $y=x$, the limit that I get is $0$ which isn't the actual limit that I've found (actual limit is $2/7$). According to a theorem, I should be getting $2/7$ instead of $0$ so I'm pretty confused now.. Can anyone tell me if my understanding of this problem is correct?

Comment: It is not surprising, the point $(2,1)$ does not belong to the line with equation $y=x$, so I do not see how the behaviour of your function on that line should tell you something about its behaviour in a neighbourhood of $(2,1)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I see, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is path independent But here the path $y = x$ itself doesn't pass through the point (2, 1), So cannot check your limit in that way.

The path must pass through the point where you want to find your limit.